# How to get execute query string in sqlite for android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using sqlite 
i want to print the query executed in db to insert

here is my code

```
// for SAving Ocean/Air sales
public int saveOrder(Order odr) throws SQLException  {
    SQLiteDatabase db = con.getWritableDatabase();
    int ordrId = 0;

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();         
    values.put("cr_usr", odr.getCrUsr());
    values.put("cr_ts", odr.getCrTs().toString());
    values.put("eat_mst_cust_id", odr.getEatMstCustId());
    values.put("ordr_dt", odr.getOrdrDt().toString());  
    String selectQuery = "SELECT last_insert_rowid()";  
    try {

        // Inserting Row
        db.insertOrThrow("eat_ordr", null, values);---getting error here for constraint failed
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        ordrId = cursor.getInt(0);
        db.close();     
    } finally {
        db.close();
    }
return ordrId;
}
```

I am not getting any error but row is failed to insert bcz it returns 0 for idvalue
so i want to see executed query how to get that query?

here is my table structure

```
CREATE TABLE "eat_ordr" ("eat_ordr_id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL , 
"eat_mst_cust_id" VARCHAR NOT NULL  REFERENCES "eat_mst_cust"("eat_mst_cust_id"), 
"ordr_no" VARCHAR NOT NULL  UNIQUE , 
"ordr_dt" DATETIME NOT NULL , 
"ordr_stat" VARCHAR NOT NULL ,
"last_sync_ts" DATETIME, 
"cr_ts" DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, "md_ts" DATETIME, "cr_usr" VARCHAR, "md_usr" VARCHAR)
```

Comment: the code comment says `getting error here` while your description says `I am not getting any error`. if you want the reason for the error: `ordr_no VARCHAR NOT NULL  UNIQUE` is not met you have not provided a value for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`insertOrThrow` documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insertOrThrow%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29) says:

> **Returns**
>   the row ID of the newly inserted row

So this can be done much easier:

```java
ordrId = db.insertOrThrow("eat_ordr", null, values);
```

Comment: You are *not* doing that, and the separate query does not work. You can check the return value.

Comment: I have not changed here.. but yes I get id value if success else catch (IllegalStateException ise) { ise.getStackTrace(); } gives me query string @ thanks CL for help